# Emacsでカーソルの位置から左方向に特定の文字を検索して置換する

Tags: emacs, elisp

中国語のピンインをEmacs上で打ちたくLispを書こうとしてるのですが、キーバインディングの変更程度しか書いたことがなく躓いています。

```
(defun make-tone-2 ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "foo"))

(define-minor-mode pinyin-mode
  "Input pinyin"
  :lighter " PinYin"
  :keymap (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
            (define-key map (kbd "2") 'make-tone-2)
            map))
```

とりあえずこのように minor-mode の定義を行い、`make-tone-2`で現在のカーソルの左方向にあるスペース以外の英文字を取得して auoi があれば、それぞれáúóí に置換しようと考えています。(ただしカーソルに一番近い文字のみ)

どの関数を使えばよいかも全くわからない状態で、どのように実装すれば良いかヒントを頂けないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make-tone-2` 関数を以下の様にしてみてはどうでしょうか。

```
(defun make-tone-2 ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((tbl '(("a" "á") ("u" "ú") ("o" "ó") ("i" "í")))
           (regexp (concat "[" (mapconcat 'car tbl "") "]")))
      (and (re-search-backward regexp nil t 1)
           (replace-match (cadr (assoc (match-string 0) tbl)))))))
```

変換する文字を変更する場合は `tbl`(assoc-list) の内容を適宜変えて下さい。

Comment: `re-search-backward`という逆向きの検索のための関数があるんですね。勉強になります。ありがとうございます。